# Only of the four images appearing in navigation

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am in the beginning stages of learning web development. I think of layouts and try to come up with a code for it.

I want to set up social media navigation on the top right of the website. I came up with the following html.

```
<nav class="snav">
<a href="#"><img src="../desktop/linked.png" height="32px" width="32px"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="../desktop/fb.png" height="32px" width="32px"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="../desktop/twitter.png" height="32px" width="32px"></a>
<a href="#"><img src="../desktop/google.png" height="32px" width="32px"></a>
</nav>
```

And the css

```
.snav {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 50px;
}

.snav a {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

but, only google + icon is appearing on screen.

Here is the complete code for the website.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../desktop/image.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  opacity: 0.5;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 0.4px solid #bd0000;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
.bar_1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0.4px solid #bd0000;
}
.bar_2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 38.33%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 23.33%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0.4px solid #bd0000;
}
.bar_3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 71.66%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 80px;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 23.33%;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0.4px solid #bd0000;
}
.bar_1:hover {
  background-color: #bd0000;
}
.bar_2:hover {
  background-color: #bd0000;
}
.bar_3:hover {
  background-color: #bd0000;
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 100vh;
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border-top: 0.4px solid #bd0000;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.search_bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 29%;
  right: 33.33%;
}
#search {
  border: 2px solid #bd0000;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5;
  font-color: #fcfcfc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#search:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-color: #000;
  opacity: 50;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
}
.mnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 515px;
}
.mnav a {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.snav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
.snav a {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Two Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="two-website.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body_con">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <nav class="mnav">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">Page 1</a>
      <a href="#">Page 2</a>
      <a href="#">Page 3</a>
    </nav>
    <img src="../desktop/logo.png">
    <nav class="snav">
      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login">
        <img src="../desktop/linked.png" height="32px" width="32px">
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
        <img src="../desktop/fb.png" height="32px" width="32px">
      </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/">
        <img src="../desktop/twitter.png" height="32px" width="32px">
      </a>
      <a href="https://plus.google.com/">
        <img src="../desktop/google.png" height="32px" width="32px">
      </a>
    </nav>
    <div class="bar_1">
    </div>
    <div class="bar_2">
    </div>
    <div class="bar_3">
    </div>
    <form action="\" method="get" class="search_bar">
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" id="search">
    </form>
  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me with it.

Thank You

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: I have been on that website before, but I am still not clear on the difference between relative positioning and absolute positioning.

All I have understood for now is that, when you set an element's position to relative, then the co-ordinates to which it moves is relative to it's original positioning and that the other elements cannot occupy the empty space.

In case of absolute positioning, the element is completely removed from it's original positioning, allowing other elements to occupy that space.

I don't know if that's correct or not. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

the width of `snav` is:

```
 5 * (32 + 5 + 5) = 5 * 42 = 210
```

so:

```
.snav {
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 50px;
width: 210px;
height: 32px;
}
```

p.s. as it is said in a comment, it is better to consider relative positioning instead of absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Add **position: relative** in **snav a** and increase the padding.

```
.snav a {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain the code please? I think it would help me better in the future if I understand codes.

Comment: @Ayush Bahugana, I have just set the position as relative. That means, with respect to the class .snav, the position of your anchor element will be relative and be adjusted by the parameters padding-left and padding-right. That's what I think! Hope it helps! :-)